# How can i use pass data from one resolver to other

Tags: angular, angular-routing, resolver

i have 2 angular resolvers works one after another. 1st

```
@Injectable()
export class ChainViewResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private a: AService) {
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return this.a.getSome(route.params['id']);
    }
}
```

and second,

```
@Injectable()
export class DocViewResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private a: AService) {
    }

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {

    return this.a.getSome(state.url.split('/')[state.url.split('/').indexOf('id') + 1]).flatMap((chain) => {
        return this.a.getSomeAnotherData(route.params['id2']).flatMap(result => {

        });
    });
}
}
```

url look like:

/parent_component/:id/children_component/:id

where 1st resolver for parent_component, and 2nd resolver for children_component

1) method **getSome** it's Heavy request, and i don't want use it 2 times, when my resolvers work together.

2) i dont want write it to some variable or to local storage, because **getSome** returned data often change, and when I use 1st resolver whithout second, I may have problems because of this

How can i pass my data from 1st resolver to 2nd?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a declaration for 1st parent route like:

```
resolve: {
    parentValue: ChainViewResolver
}
```

you may get it in child DocViewResolver like:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {

    let parentValue = route.parent.data.parentValue; // <-- here

    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As result I use Service named TmpService to pass data from one resolver to other, it work, but i don t like this this decision.